# Clicar no botão e salvar arquivo xml no server side

Tags: php, xml, xmldocument

Olá,estou construindo uma aplicação com PHP,acontece que tenho um botão que ao clicar ele gera um file.xml na pasta downloads,acredito que por default,mas quero gerar este file.xml em uma folder específica que guarda meus files.xml.

Vi alguns exemplos usando a função preg_match,mas ele somente mudou o nome do arquivo adicionando um underline ou ponto,mas não salvou na folder de destino.

Este é meu código para gerar o xml de pessoa:

```
<?php
  class RetornaPessoa_XML{
        public function Pessoa_xmlGen($pessoaweb_id){
             require_once('connection.php');
             $sql = "SELECT pessoas.pessoaweb_id,
                            pessoas.nome,
                            pessoas.cpf_cnpj,
                            pessoas.rg_ie
             FROM   pessoas
             WHERE  pessoas.pessoaweb_id =".$pessoaweb_id;

       $stmt = ibase_query($conn, $sql);
       $data = [];
       $i = 0;
       $fileName = "../_xxx_Pessoa_id-".$pessoaweb_id;
      while($row = ibase_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
       $data[$i]['pessoaweb_id'] = $pessoaweb_id;
       $data[$i]['nome'] = $row['NOME'];
       $data[$i]['cpf_cnpj'] = $row['CPF_CNPJ'];
       $data[$i]['rg_ie'] = $row['RG_IE'];
       $i++;
      }
//CHAMA A CLASSE EXPORT, COLOCA DENTRO DE UMA VARIÁVEL
    //E EM SEGUIDA USA SUA FUNÇÃO, QUE MONTA E RETORNA UM ARQUIVO XML
    require_once('pessoa_setXML.php');
    $export = new Export();

    if(isset($pessoaweb_id)){
        $export->xml($fileName, $data, $pessoaweb_id);
    }
    // echo "<script>alert('chegou 2!');</script>";
    return true;
    }
 }  
?>
```

E AQUI É O CÓDIGO PARA SETAR O XML,MONTA O XML COM OS PARÂMETROS FORNECIDOS

```
class Export{

public function xml($fileName, $data, $pessoaweb_id){
//RECEBE AS INFORMAÇÕES POR PARÂMETRO E MONTA O XML COM OS DADOS FORNECIDOS

    $file = "{$fileName}.xml";
    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>";
    $xml .= "<DATAPACKET VERSION='1.0'>";
    $xml .= "<METADATA>";
    $xml .= "<FIELDS>";
    $xml .= "<FIELD WIDHT='64' FIELDTYPE='Integer' ATTRNAME='PESSOA_ID'/>";
    $xml .= "<FIELD WIDHT='64' FIELDTYPE='Integer' ATTRNAME='NOME'/>";
    $xml .= "<FIELD WIDHT='64' FIELDTYPE='Integer' 
    ATTRNAME='NOMEFANTASIA'/>";
    $xml .= "<FIELD WIDHT='300' FIELDTYPE='Integer' ATTRNAME='CPF_CNPJ'/>";
    $xml .= "<FIELD WIDHT='300' FIELDTYPE='Integer' ATTRNAME='RG_IE'/>";
    $xml .= "<FIELD WIDHT='300' FIELDTYPE='Integer' 
    ATTRNAME='PESSOAWEB_ID'/>";
    $xml .= "</FIELDS>";        
    $xml .= "</METADATA>";      
    $xml .= "<{$fileName}>";
    $xml .= "<ROWDATA>";        
    for($i = 0; $i < count($data);$i++){
        $xml .= "<ROW>";
    $xml .= "<ROW PEDIDOWEB_ID='{$data[$i]['pessoaweb_id']}' 
RG_IE='{$data[$i]['rg_ie']}'
                  CPF_CNPJ='{$data[$i]['cpf_cnpj']}' 
NOMEFANTASIA='NOMEFANTASIA' 
                  NOME='{$data[$i]['nome']}' PESSOA_ID='PESSOA_ID'/>";
        $xml .= "</ROW>";
    }

    $xml .= "</ROWDATA>";       
    $xml .= "</{$fileName}>";       
    $xml .= "</DATAPACKET>";

    // CONFIGURA O HEADER PARA DOWNLOAD
    header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
    header("Content-Type: application/xml");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file}\"");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    // ENVIA CONTEÚDO
    echo $xml;
}
}
```

Comment: Já tentou definir o caminho absoluto em `$fileName`? Lembre-se de verificar as permissões do diretório.

Comment: Seria a pasta Downloads do seu computador?

Comment: Está fazendo o download deste arquivo para c:\DOWNLOADS por default,mas quero que mande para folder c:\AQR_XML